# Is 6% of your dataset are outliers normal?

Tags: r, dataset, outliers

My dataset has 80,886 obs and 16 variables. I am using Mahalanobis Distance to detect outliers. And use P-value less than 0.001 as the cut-off. I am getting 5,423 obs as outlier which is 6% of total obs. Is this considered normal or is something interesting going on in my dataset?

Comment: So you used a measure with an arbitrary cut-off value and got an arbitrary number of "outliers" as a result, now what? What do you want to do with these arbitrary values? Why are you doing this, what is your goal?

Comment: As you may know, a common criterion for 'outlier' is based on boxplots. Some distributions (exponential, Weibull, Pareto) have very heavy tails and hence large proportions of boxplot outliers. Among standard exponential samples of size 1000, about 4.8% of observations are outliers. I would not be astonished if some families of distributions had 6% or more. In R, one simulation: `prop.out = replicate(10^5, length(boxplot.stats(rexp(1000))$out)/1000); mean(prop.out)` returned $0.04819785.$ You might try a few simulations for your data using your criteria.

Comment: What do you mean that you’re using a p-value of $0.001?$ Mahalanobis distance isn’t a hypothesis test, so I am confused about how a p-value arises.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that, by p-value $p$, you mean a Mahalanobis distance $d$ corresponding to $P(d\ge \chi^2_{df}) \le p$. For your particular case, that would be $P(d\ge \chi^2_{16}) \le 0.001$.

The $\chi^2$ formulation of Mahalanobis distance corresponds to multivariate Gaussian distributions, much as the $68$-$95$-$99.7$ "empirical rule" corresponds to univariate Gaussians.

You are looking for Mahalanobis distances that are supposed to be in the top $0.1\%$ of Mahalanobis distances, and you observing that $6\%$ of your distances are that far away.

In other words, you are observing "outliers" sixty times as often as a multivariate Gaussian with your estimated means and covariance matrix would expect.

Consequently, I would say that a multivariate Gaussian distribution is not a great model for your data.

However, it is totally routine to observe more "outliers" than a normal distribution would predict. It just means that the assumption of a normal distribution is a poor assumption.